# How do I convert stdClass to my custom class recursively?

Tags: php, object, recursion, casting, stdclass

I have an object of class stdClass, which contains other objects of the same class. How do I rename all stdClasses of that object to my custom class which is named 'AppCategory' ?

I've found this function to cast object into a class, but it doesn't work recursively :( It only renames the main object, not it's children.

```
function cast($object, $class) {
    if( !is_object($object) ) 
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$object must be an object.');
    if( !is_string($class) )
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$class must be a string.');
    if( !class_exists($class) )
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Unknown class: %s.', $class));
    if( !is_subclass_of($class, get_class($object)) )
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
            '%s is not a descendant of $object class: %s.',
            $class, get_class($object)
        ));

    /**
     * This is a beautifully ugly hack.
     *
     * First, we serialize our object, which turns it into a string, allowing
     * us to muck about with it using standard string manipulation methods.
     *
     * Then, we use preg_replace to change it's defined type to the class
     * we're casting it to, and then serialize the string back into an
     * object.
     */



    logToFile(print_r($x, true), false, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/administrator/components/com_apps/log.php', 'a');



    return unserialize(
        preg_replace(
            '/^O:\d+:"[^"]++"/', 
            'O:'.strlen($class).':"'.$class.'"',
            serialize($object)
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
foreach($object as &$prop) {
    if(is_object($prop)) {
        $prop = cast($prop, $class);
    }
}    

return unserialize(
        preg_replace(
            '/^O:\d+:"[^"]++"/', 
            'O:'.strlen($class).':"'.$class.'"',
            serialize($object)
        )
    );
```